# Multipart file upload and ng serve: Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am working on the front end of a file upload service. I am currently ignoring the service path with respect to the backend. I have run into a strange problem. I have a few generated components that sit within the app component. When I end the serve from console and do *ng serve* again, it errors out. It says: [image: ng serve error]

The only way I have found to get rid of this is to erase my uploader service injection, save the file, then re-insert the injection. This is how it is supposed to look: 
[image]

The only way to get ng serve to work is to by erasing the line *private service: UploaderService*

Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing something with my injection? My UploaderService is marked as Injectable() and the components that use it are under Directives.

**Update:**
What I found out is that it is unrelated to the UploaderService. I have a component that does not inject the UploaderService. I fix it the same way I fix the other components that inject the UploaderService. By deleting the parameters of the constructor, saving, and then putting the parameters back. Then it will serve

**Update2:** 
The generated componenet, upload.component.t, has a spec file that is generated with it, *upload.component.spec.ts*

It has a error that asks for parameters like so:[image]

My UploadComponent constructor has a parameter in it, where i inject the UploaderService. In the spec.ts file, a new UploadCompent is created, but does not contain any arguments. I am guessing this is where I am going wrong. How do I work around this?

Here is my UploaderService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers, HTTP_BINDINGS, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { ItemEntryComponent } from './item-entry';
import { Query } from './Query';


@Injectable()
export class UploaderService {
  public URL: string;
  private query: Query;
  public filesSelected: Array<ItemEntryComponent> = [];

  progress$: any;
  progress: any;
  progressObserver: any;

  //CONSTRUCTOR
  constructor(private http: Http) {

    //***SET URL***
    this.URL = 'http://localhost:7547/api/picker';
    //Create Query for url
    this.query = new Query(this.URL);

    //Create progress attribute
    this.progress$ = Observable.create(observer => {
      this.progressObserver = observer
    }).share();
  }
}
```

Comment: By erasing the private attribute it should probably work, how would it be private if you are passing the parameter as constructor?

Comment: @juvian I gave that a try. What I found out is that it is unrelated to the UploaderService. I have a component that does not inject the UploaderService. I fix it the same way I fix the other components that inject the UploaderService. By deleting the parameters of the constructor, saving, and then putting the parameters back. Then it will serve.

Comment: Weird, but glad you got it fixed

Comment: @juvian While it is fixed, it is only temporary. When I leave at the end of the day and come back to it tomorrow, I will have to delete all of the parameters in the constructors of all my components. This is okay for now, but as the project  grows, this will become a bigger issue.

Comment: As a short term solution, you could replace your constructors parameters with a unique identifier and then with another language such as java or python you could replace those identifiers in the files with an empty string or with what you want depending on a boolean condiiton. Hope a more experienced user with typescript/angular2 comes up with a real solution

Comment: Have you added upload service in provider of the component. Your typescript version? Show us code of upload service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I had not realized the generated files included a spec testing file, in my example it was *upload.component.spec.ts*. Getting rid of those files gets rid of the errors that ask for parameters to be filled in inside the test files and now ng serve works.